# antlr 2 rule ambiguity

Tags: antlr2

```
   DECIMAL_LITERAL : ('0' | '1'..'9' ('0'..'9')*) (INTEGER_TYPE_SUFFIX)? ;

   FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL

   :   ('0'..'9')+ 

       (
           DOT ('0'..'9')* (EXPONENT)? (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
       |   EXPONENT (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
       |   FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX
       )
       |   DOT ('0'..'9')+ (EXPONENT)? (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
   ;
```

DECIMAL_LITERAL match int literal in c language and FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL match float literal in c language.But when the lexer meet a float ,such as 3.44, 3 will match rule DECIMAL_LITERAL.

What can I do to make it recognize float literal?

Answer (score 0):

You combine the rules into one lexer rule and then change the type based on whether you see the `DOT` or not.  This should give you an idea, although it's not exactly equivalent what you had written above.

```
DECIMAL_LITERAL 
:   ('0'..'9')+ 
   (
       DOT { _ttype = FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL; } ('0'..'9')* (EXPONENT)? (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
   |   EXPONENT (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
   |   FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX
   )
   |   DOT { _ttype = FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL; } ('0'..'9')+ (EXPONENT)? (FLOAT_TYPE_SUFFIX)?
;
```

For a more complete example see my C grammar at http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/cgram/